# How to modify last element of Python list in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list

I have a code segment like following which throws an invalid syntax error:

```
lst = [0, 0, 0]
new_lst = [lst[-1] = i + 1 for i in range(3)]
```

Basically, I want `new_lst` to be list of lists, where every list will be `lst` but the last element changed. Any ideas how to do this in Python?

Comment: Assignments are not allowed inside of list comprehensions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only make assignments when they are stand-alone statements I.e. not within a list comprehension. Other examples of this would be in control statements like `if`s or `for`s

```
In [945]: lst = [0, 0, 0]

In [946]: new_lst = [lst[:-1] + [i + 1] for i in range(3)]

In [947]: new_lst
Out[947]: [[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 3]]
```

`lst[:-1]` takes every element from `lst` except for the last and `[i + 1]` will be appended to the end of the list

Comment: @terett if it works and has helped you please upvote and accept the answer. thanks!